# vue-i18n-plugin does not work properly

Tags: javascript, internationalization, vue.js

I am trying to use [**this plugin**](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-i18n) to translate my app and everything were working fine until I had to use the format filter to replace values!

It replace the tags properly but when I have any changes on the replaced obj it does not apply to the message!

As an example I have something similar to the DataTables where I have the message: "Showing {0} entries".. When it first loads works fine! But when I search for something through the filter filterBy the number does not change on the message!

Somebody?

My view: `{{ $i18n.messages.data_grid_entries_showing | format listLength }}`

where listLength is a computed as bellow
`listLength () { return this.list.length; }`

**------------UPDATED----------**

I just change the plugin that I am using! I think it's almost the same but the now one looks more active than the other... but the problem remains...
https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

There is a example code! First shows `Showing 1 entries`, it should increment when clicking on the button but it doesn't! The VALUE increment properly but it does not show the changes on the message!

**JS**

```
Vue.use(i18n, {
  lang: 'en-US',
  locales: {
    "en-US": {
      message: "Showing {0} entries"
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 1
  },
  methods: {
    incrementValue: function() {
      this.value++;
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  {{ $t('message', [value]) }}
  <button @click="incrementValue()">Click to increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to show us your code

Comment: Sorry @Jeff! Just added an example!